# Why is NPM install with packagename working in Docker but 'NPM install" not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am building a docker file in a node.js application. If I install packages this way, it works:

```
RUN npm install express
RUN npm install axios
RUN npm install cloudinary
```

These packages will install. I have about 12 packages for this application and running their installation one by one like this doesn't seem okay to me.
But if I run the entire installations at once like this:

```
RUN npm install
```

Once it gets to the `npm installation` part, it would hang on for more than 7 minutes and eventually fails with this error:

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install --only=production]: exit code: 1
```

What could be causing this?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
## multi stage system
FROM node:lts-alpine

 # create root application folder
 WORKDIR /app

 # copy configs to /app folder
 COPY package.json ./
 COPY package-lock.json ./
 COPY tsconfig.json ./
 COPY ecosystem.config.js ./
 # copy source code to /app/src folder
 COPY src /app/src
 RUN npm install

 RUN npm run build



 FROM node:lts-alpine

 WORKDIR /app
 COPY package.json ./ 
 COPY package-lock.json ./

 RUN npm install --omit=dev

 RUN npm install pm2 -g

  COPY --from=0 /app/build ./build


  RUN npm uninstall typescript



   USER node

   CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"]

   EXPOSE 5000
```

I am running this on windows 11

Comment: Can you post the entire Dockerfile?

Comment: Did you try running [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) instead? It seems a better choice for this use case.

Comment: Let me try that and see. Thank you

Comment: Maybe it has to do with windows 11 and docker deskstop versions. My coding partner who uses IOS system still used same npm install and it worked and built the image, same dockerfile. We built the application together, we have same codes. But this doesnt work for me except I install the applications one by one.

Comment: please show your package.json, all dependensies as in package,json ro be exact

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to use this workaround: I simply mentioned all the packages I want to install as part of package.json script and ran that script in docker build.

```
"install": "npm install axios bcrypt cloudinary express jsonwebtoken multer mysql2 nodemailer nodemailer-express-handlebars nodemailer-sendgrid sequelize socket.io ",
```

In dockerfile, I did `RUN npm run install`